# Discrete math functions proof

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathbb N_{\text{even}}$ be the set of all natural even numbers, and  $\mathbb N_{\text{odd}}$ be the set of all natural odd numbers,
the function $f:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\to \mathcal P(\mathbb N_{\text{even}}) \times\mathcal P(\mathbb N_{\text{odd}})$ is defined like this: $$f(A) = (A \cap \mathbb N_{\text{even}}, A\cap \mathbb N_{\text{odd}})$$ Show the inverse function of $f$.

Obviously the inverse function would have to be something like this:

$$g:\mathcal P(\mathbb N_{\text{even}}) \times \mathcal P(\mathbb N_{\text{odd}}) \to \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$$

But I just can't seem to solve this problem, can someone guide me what is the best approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever confused, it's always worth looking at a specific example.

Suppose $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Then what is $f(A)$?

Can you now imagine how the inverse works?

Answer (score 0):

$$g(A\times B)=A\cup B.$$
Now prove this is indeed the inverse.